# Zigzag type of Listview in android

Tags: android

I want to make ListView in android like this [image]

this is possible in iPhone ,in iPhone they used to call it Circle view

Comment: Have you found the solution? If yes then please post you answer here.

Answer (score 2):

It also possible using xml.jst u need to inflate rowLayout then add "Padding" to its view.
The below code execute properly

Please try the below code..

```
public class MainActivity  extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
ListView lv;
int [] arr={20,40,60,80,80,60,40,20};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    lv=getListView();
    CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(this, arr);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

}

write below getview method in your customAdapter. change the array as per your requirement

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);
    LinearLayout llInside = new LinearLayout(context);

    ll.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    llInside.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tv.setText("this is textbview");
    tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


    llInside.addView(tv);       


     //the padding is set here dynamically

    int rem = position % 8;
    Log.d("" + rem, "" + rem);
    llInside.setPadding(img[rem], 0, 0,0 );   

    ll.addView(llInside);
    return ll;
}
```

Output[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't need to be too dynamic you could use a scroll view, which contains a LinearLayout, and have textViews inside it with different padding on the left which would stagger them like this, but it would take a while to do and wouldn't be very dynamic in terms of length. I can't think of any other way to do this in android though.

Something like this, and after a few start decrementing the padding to get the zig zag

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="TextView" />  
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```